# How to concatenate backslash with shell variable

Tags: bash

Say I have this:

```
foo="bar"
echo "\$foo"
```

That won't work because it will escape the `$`.
I just want to concatenate the backslash with the content of variable `foo`.

Comment: `echo "\\$bar"` will escape the backslash. But it will only print the backslash of course as your variable is empty. --> `echo "\\$foo"`

Answer (score 1):

One way is mentioned by [h0ch5tr4355](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5316879/h0ch5tr4355) in a comment, another way you can try if you just want to print and concern with out put then you can try this.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo="bar"
echo '\'$foo
```

As mentioned in comment, I am also expecting that you try print **foo** instead of **bar**, as **bar** is empty.

[Single-Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)

[Double-Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this was a dumb question, one solution is as simple as:

```
foo='bar' 
back_slash='\' 

echo "$back_slash$foo"
```

or if you want to be extra careful:

```
echo "${back_slash}${foo}"
```